# Python standard logging

Tags: python, logging

I like using the python logging module because it standardizes my application and easier to get metrics. The problem I face is, for every application (or file.py) I am keep putting this on top of my code.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
if not os.path.exists('log'):
    os.makedirs('log')

logName=time.strftime("%Y%m%d.log")    
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('log/%s'%(logName))

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(funcName)s %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

ch.setFormatter(formatter)
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
```

This is tedious and repetitive. Is there a better way to do this?
How do people log for a large application with multiple modules?

Comment: Why are you putting that in every file?

Comment: I now created a file called 'mylogging.py' and then do "import mylogging"

Comment: thats what i thought.. why not just push all the shared code to one file and call is from different files, if possible, inherit that class

Comment: Aside: don't create loggers as module globals, keep them local inside functions.  See http://victorlin.me/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python in the "Do not get logger at the module level" section.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

If you wrap the `basicConfig()` in a function then you can just import your function and pass specific args (i.e. log *filename*, *format*, *level*, etc).

It will help to condense the code a bit and make it more extensible.

For example -

```
import logging

def test_logging(filename, format):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=filename, format=format, level=logging.DEBUG)

    # test
    logging.info('Info test...')
    logging.debug('Debug test...')
```

Then just import the `test_logging()` function into other programs.

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Using logging in multiple modules](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules) from [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html).

What you need to do is to use getLogger() function to get a logger with a pre-defined settings.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('some_logger')
```

You set those settings just once at application startup time.